# Cannot enable prod mode after setup

Tags: angular, angular5

When I try to enable prod mode in my Stack Blitz it sometimes tells me

> Cannot enable prod mode after setup

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-fv1bhs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because of HMR. It doesn't reload the window so the old platform instance is still there, so it tries to reinitalize the new instance but the old one is like "nope, we already started"

So the answer is basically to close/open the preview window.

I hope it works ;D