# Angular why the built application is giving an error of cannot enable prod mode?

Tags: angular, dev-mode

I've built my angular application using `ng build --prod` and when I tried to launch it, an error appeared saying:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot enable prod mode after platform setup.

In my `api.service.ts` at the top of the service I used `isDevMode()` in case I am testing on localhost:

```
if (isDevMode()) {
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      // 'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa(user + ":" + password),
      'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(`${user}:${password}`)}`,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    })
  };
} else {
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'

    })
  };
}
```

At `main.ts`:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

And at the `environment.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false
};
```

I tried to check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721206/how-to-enable-production-mode) in stack overflow but no results from it and this post on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3495).

**EDIT**

environment.prod.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

Comment: Did you see this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983242/cannot-enable-prod-mode-after-setup

Comment: @Zze exactly. but I tried to reload and reopen the browser but still the same.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8340#issuecomment-350289000

Comment: So the code your showed above is outside of the service class?

Comment: @David yes. Moving the conditions within the class would solve the problem?

Comment: The assignment should be done after the class has been initialised. So moving it to a static class variable and assigning it straight away will lead you to the same issue.

Comment: @David so should I move it inside the class?

Comment: @alim1990 Yes you can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call `isDevMode()` before `enableProdMode` is called (see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8340))).

You are importing `AppModule` in your `main.ts` file before calling `enableProdMode`. That import will in turn import your service file, which has the `isDevMode` check outside of the class from what I understood.

Try moving the initialisation of `httpOptions` in your service constructor.

**Note** If the variable is static and initialised when it's declared, you'll have the same issue.

If you want to leave the initialisation outside of the class, you could check your environment instead

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

 if (environment.production) {
    httpOptions = {
```

Btw, the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a server response header and should not be set on a client side request.

Comment: So the best way is to wrap the http options inside `envirmment.production` instead of using `isDevMode()`?

Comment: I think so. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535386/how-to-check-if-angular-application-running-in-production-or-development-mode